# bash: difference between Process Substitution and Command Substitution

Tags: bash

Is there a significant difference between `Command Substitution` and `Process Substitution`?

All of the commands below give the same result: fill `variable` with the single-line, newline terminated content.

Should one preferred over the other?

```
variable="`/usr/bin/echo a b c`"
variable="$(/usr/bin/echo a b c)"
read variable < <(/usr/bin/echo a b c)
```

Comment: The significant difference is that the command substitution evaluates to the output of the command, while the process substitution evaluates to the name of a file that *contains* the name of the command. Sometimes, you don't have a choice for which you require. (Consider a command that cannot read from standard input, but only from a named file.)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a significant difference between Command Substitution and Process Substitution?

Sure.

| Command | Process |
| --- | --- |
| POSIX very standard | Bash extension |
| no pipes | opens a pipe for communication |
| always works | requires operating system support for creating a pipe |
| is replaced by the output of commands | is replaced by a pipe name |

> Should one preferred over the other?

It is apples and oranges. Command substitution should always be preferred *when possible*.

If you need to get command output, then you should use command substitution.

If you need to interactively read from a command as a stream, then you should use process substitution *and* make a command read from that stream, with by redirection `<` or by passing the pipe name to the command.

There is also a slight case where zero bytes can be transferred using a stream, but can't be stored in a command substitution result.

> variable="`/usr/bin/echo a b c`"

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 . Backslashes are handled differently.

> read variable < <(/usr/bin/echo a b c)

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . `read` removes leading and trailing whitespaces and missing `-r` handles backslashes.